# Java applets are no longer supported - what's the alternative? (File manipulation - shell commands)

Tags: java, shell, applet, xpages, file-management

I have a question about how to manipulate files from the browser, currently we are using a java applet. To create some folders, replace/delete save some files/folders and execute a shell command with parameters. As we know Chrome no longer supports the npapi and therefor java applets, FireFox will soon follow and my guess is that IE will not stay behind forever.

So the actual question is what's the best way to go?
Should we think about creating plugins (but this then should be done for all major browsers - a lot of work)

Or do you recommend to install an external program, what we can launch on the users system? By for instance associating a specific extension, or by adding a url scheme?

What about this Java Web Start? Does this allow us to communicate with the domino api?

Any other technologies that would be better?

The website we are building is using IBM Domino 9.0.1 XPages (JSF).

Comment: Why do you need to touch the files on the system of the client?

Comment: You can use HTML5 File Api http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi if you want to keep it inside the borwser. For shell commands i don't know any solution. Otherwise convert your applet into an standalone application (cheaper solution).

Comment: @Ferrybig We are making our Lotus Notes document managing system available through the web and in the same time we are trying to get rid of Lotus Notes clients...

Comment: Ping me on Sametime, Whatsapp or Skype. I'll walk you through the solution

Comment: You should have a look at Electron: http://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your use case: content management system.

For adding files the HTML5 files API should do all you need. There are plenty of examples including multi file uploads.

It gets trickier when you want to provide a round-trip edit experience. Like you click something and Word, Excel, Impress, Photoshop opens and you edit. When you save it all goes back to Domino.

The solution here is wevDAV. You can even expose Domino views as folders in Explorer / Finder / Nautilus.

For Domino there is a project on OpenNTF that implements WebDAV for documents/attachments on Domino (I wrote it). It might be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for this, very interesting - totally forgot about WebDav!
This gets us in the good direction indeed. What we need does go beyond this. But the technique used is what I was looking. I will be creating an application that uses the url scheme/protocol. The helper is a good start but in the end, we need to do a lot of things... So not just editing I'm afraid. How can I send a file back to my domino database from this external program? Or even access the domino documents, so I can return some messages and attachments without using the Lotus Notes client dll? Probably WebServices, right?

Comment: @Kraeven: that's domino client/server programming, which, I presume, you're better at than us, since you're in charge of porting a domino application...

Comment: Question fallacy: asking for a detailed step without stating purpose. A web application would do the bulk of its operation on the server side. So you might need to rearchitect your solution to not fall into the trap to have a Notes client in HTML instead of a web application / trap: the first user who wants to use it with a mobile device

Comment: I was not looking for a detailed description 'yet', but I was more curious in what the alternatives could be. :-) Indeed I see the confusion, let me elaborate a bit... It's an existing application written in LS/formula (>15 years), used only on our corporate windows machines in the extent of file manipulations. Simple file download/upload and some meta data editing is now done via XPages (also on mobile). To get rid of the notes clients, we'll need to provide them with a web based solution (only windows) on which they can do file manipulations, start applications with company macro's and so on

Comment: It breaks down to: open a file. Execute the macros in that file. Save the file back? So you make friends with Apache POI to get the macros into the office files and WebDAV does the rest.

Comment: Well there's more to it... :-D We need to be able to launch several programs like Office/AutoCAD/MicroStation and other drawing packages. Just to give you an idea of a possible scenario.You could have 5 different AutoCAD versions on your machine, the program started is defined on a project level. The new file is derived from a template (on a network location or embedded in a notes doc), then extra meta data is exported in a file that the specified macro will read-out to populate the drawing border for instance. In the end you could have several new files that need to be saved back to the db.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should be making a distinction here:

- things like file access can be done using HTML5 file access, but
- things like local administration definitely aren't something that need or should be done from within the browser.

In fact, I always hated that Java suggested that users "need not install any software" to do this and that on their machine, which was a straight lie, considering they downloaded Java Software, had to tell their Java Policy framework to trust that and then that software was able to make local changes. That's just as unsecure as downloading any (signed) executable and making your user execute it.

Java's portability¹ doesn't apply to your use case, as it seems; "executing a shell command" sounds as non-portable as it gets. So, in the end, you either only have one platform you address, or one solution for every platform, in which case you gain no portability by the fact that the same Java executable can run on all JREs (given that's the case, even).

I'd say: It's a good time to let Java for Desktops die, especially since you don't seem to be doing anything that Java is good at² in your application.

As it sounds, the average installer framework can do what you want without you writing any code. There's plenty out there, especially for Windows, which you seem to be addressing; take microsoft's .MSI as an example. You'd end up with a two click, signable, trustable, updateable solution that wouldn't need the user to keep a JRE installed or secure at all.

**CLARIFICATION**: I really don't *hate* Java; I don't find it's the greatest language or has the best ecosystem, but whatever makes your application work is fine.

Now, you mention:

> To be clear, we are creating a Document Managing System, which used to be on the Lotus Notes client and that we are trying to port to the Web.

That does in fact sound like it might be a good idea to chose any browser and embed that. In fact, Firefox is "merely" an application around a browser core, and you might just modify it (e.g. by writing an extension) to fit your needs. It's not really a "web application", that way, but it would meet your requirements of integration with a web application and local administrative access. I furthermore recommend thinking twice about the shell scripts you need to run locally -- maybe their job can be more easily replaced by another program or even something that is "web compatible" than calling them with local privileges from your web application.

---

¹ (which was a big thing back in the day, but honestly, Java applications nowadays are about as portable as your average .Net or Qt based application on desktop OSes, but never quite feel completely like home -- it's like *portabilities ugly sister* if you're portable, but only offer the minimal common subset of functionality and look and feel on each platform)

² ... whatever that might be!

Comment: Yes this was my guess as well, we need a program on the local windows client that's able to do those things with local admin rights. To be clear, we are creating a Document Managing System, which used to be on the Lotus Notes client and that we are trying to port to the Web. I know this is not something the browser was built for, in fact a good browser should never allow such a thing. That being said, making our application accessible from the Web is a real requirement.

Comment: Rambling about how you dislike Java isn't helping the question. It does however have entertainment value